# How to input colored text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change the color in EditText dynamically.
To be specific:

After I pressed a <kbd>button</kbd>, the text I input to the `EditText` turns **color red**;(the text already in the EditText remains its' original color)

After I press the <kbd>button</kbd> again , the text I input to the `EditText` turns some other color,also, the color of the text which already in the `EditText` remains.

Comment: Set up an `onClickListener` for the button along with perhaps a boolean called `isPressed`.  If `isPressed` is false, use @Sunil's answer and set `isPressed` to true.  That way when the user presses it again, you can check for `isPressed` and since it is true, set it to false and revert the EditText's color to original.

Comment: the effect i want is different kinds of color in one edittext, for example: first i inupt "abc" ,they are black,and now i press the button, and go on to input "def",i want "abc" remains black but "def" changes to red, and i press again , input "123","abc" is black, "def" is red and "123" becomes some other color!

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the following code to set text color of your edit text

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
// to set text color using RGB code
et.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
```

Comment: In addition to this answer, use [this link](http://immigration-usa.com/html_colors.html) to find what colors you want (replace the 6 characters after the `#` symbol in this answer with the 6 of the color you want).

Comment: you can use http://html-color-codes.info/ also to choose your color and get its rgb code

Comment: maybe you misunderstand what i mean~~  what i want is different kinds of color in one edittext, for example: first i inupt "abc" ,they are black,and now i press the button, and go on to input "def",i want "abc" remains black but "def" changes to red, and i press again , input "123","abc" is black, "def" is red and "123" becomes some other color!

Comment: Do you mean: have text hard-coded into the EditText that is some color e.g. black, but what the user enters after that is another color e.g. red, and once a button is pressed, the hard-coded text remains black while the red text turns another color e.g. blue?  If this is a case, why not make a TextView for the hard-coded text and an EditText for.. well.. what can actually be edited?

Comment: the reason why i use edittext is that :I'll post what user input to a website , website use css for color ,so i want user see the color effect while inputting text

Comment: If you're using `css` for color, I suggest you tag the question with `css` so those people can help.  Sadly, I'm unsure how to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
Spannable spannable = youreditText.getText();
spannable .setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.argb(a, r, g, b)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

If you don't want the inserted text to be colored but you want a text beetween indexes colored simply use:

```
Spannable spannable = youreditText.getText();
spannable .setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.argb(a, r, g, b)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can able to apply color to your edittext as like:

```
yourEdiText.setTextColor(0xff0000ff);
```

and for specific situation you have to put that code.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out a simple solution by using a tag like HTML

```
ImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
    @override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mContentEdit.append("[1;34m [m");  //this is the tag I use
        //here I simplely append new tag to the end ,we can also add this tag where cursor is
    }
});
```

add a TextWatcher for my EditText;

```
    mContentEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(mInsertIndex){
            case 1:
                mSelection = mContentEdit.getSelectionStart();
                break;
            case 2:  
                mContentEdit.setSelection(mSelection);
                break;   //recover the cursor's position
            }
            }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (mInsertIndex) {
            case 1:
                //this is p:Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[[\\d{1};]*(3\\d{1})m(.*?)\\[[\\d;]*m");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(s.toString());
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                while(m.find()){
                    m.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=#"+CssUtil.getColor(m.group(1))+">"+"[1;"+m.group(1)+"m"+m.group(2)+"[m"+"</font>");
                } //add a tag otherwise the next time we input,color will be gone;
                m.appendTail(sb);
                mInsertIndex = 2;
                mContentEdit.setText(Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
                break;
                                    //replace tag by html color
            case 2:
                mInsertIndex = 1;
                break;
                                    //avoid recursive message loop
            }

        }
```

this code does good job for my application. I can post the raw text in edittext directly to website, and website will parse the tags for css color;

But there is still defect:

1: What if I don't want see the tags?
   In my question , what I need is actually a color state machine,once btn pressed ,where ever u input ,the color will make effect. But in my solution ,I have to input in the tags.

2:With the growth of the input length, efficiency might be a problem;
   As u see, a regex is employed;

So, still looking forward to a hero to solve my problem!